# Javascript - Google closure annotating attribute types

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have Javascript UI objects like this:

```
function MyUIElement() {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "my_element_x";
    div.innerHTML = "whatever";
    ...

    this.hide = function() {
        div.style.display = "none";
    };

    this.show = function() {
        div.style.display = "block";
    };

    this.showData = function(data) {
        ...
    }

    this.div = div;
}

function addUIElement(element) {
    app_div.appendChild(element);
}

myElement = new MyUIElement();
addUIElement(myElement.div)
```

I noticed that Closure compiler doesn't know the type of myElement.div, so I added a type for it:

```
function MyUIElement = {
    /**
     * @type {Element}
     */
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "my_element_x";
    div.innerHTML = "whatever";
    ...
```

But it still doesn't know the type. I have to annotate "this.div = div" for it to recognize the type.

I'm just wondering what the best/common solution to this kind of scenario is. Should I use this.div for every access to my div to avoid annotating it twice? Is there some other way I should be controlling public/private variables of my MyUIElement class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several syntax errors. Try removing the global variable `div` and correcting the function declaration (ie `function MyUIElement() {`). Also `this.showData` is declared incorrectly.

```
function MyUIElement() {
    /**
     * @type {Element}
     */
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "my_element_x";
    div.innerHTML = "whatever";
```

Correcting those issues let it compile for me correctly: [compiled](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/code/jsc7c7933f82325d31b336c90252f0618ef/default.js) and [uncompiled](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/code/jsc7c7933f82325d31b336c90252f0618ef/default.js)

If you're compiling in advanced (you never specified) you'll need to add some hints to the compiler for constructors and what is considered a publicly accessible variable on `this`

```
/**
 * some description
 * @expose
 * @constructor Necessary to specify that this is a constructor function
 */
var MyUIElement = function() {
    /** @expose expose means this is accessible to the public don't minimize the var name */
    var div = this.div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "my_element_x";
    div.innerHTML = "whatever";

    /** @expose */
    this.hide = function() {
        div.style.display = "none";
    };

    /** @expose */
    this.show = function() {
        div.style.display = "block";
    };

    /** @expose */
    this.showData = function(data) {

    }
}
var myElement = new MyUIElement();
```

Comment: Fixed them, thanks. Still not really relevant to my question.

Comment: It worked when I compiled the snippet in simple and advanced so whats the issue? You still have a global variable `div`. Try `var div = this.div = ...` and I'm assuming you're using advanced comp correct?

Comment: `@expose` is now deprecated. Authors should migrate their code to use `@export` instead.